# Finding the degree of an undirected graph

Tags: python

I am trying to find the degree distribution of an undirected graph. And I tried the following code:

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
          "b" : ["c", "e"],
          "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
          "d" : ["c"],
          "e" : ["c", "b"],
          "f" : []
        }

def generate_edges(graph):
    edges = []
    for node in graph:
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            edges.append((node, neighbour))

    return edges

print(generate_edges(graph))
```

And my output is something like this :

```
[('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'e'), ('a', 'c'), ('e', 'c'), ('e', 'b'), ('d', 'c')]
```

I am trying to find the degree but I am not getting it. I need my output to be [1,2,2,0,1] which is a list, where the index value range from 0 to maximum degree in the graph(i.e in the above graph 4 is the maximum degree for "c") and the index values are number of nodes with degree equal to that index. ( in the above above graph, there is 1 node with 0 degrees,2 with 1 degree and again 2 with 2 degrees,none with 3 degree and finally 1 with 4 degree). Hence [1,2,2,0,4]. Can anyone help me with this without using NetworkX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
          "b" : ["c", "e"],
          "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
          "d" : ["c"],
          "e" : ["c", "b"],
          "f" : [] }

def max_length(x):
    return len(graph[x])

# Determine what index has the longest value
index = max(graph, key=max_length)
m = len(graph[index])

# Fill the list with `m` zeroes
out = [0 for x in range(m+1)]

for k in graph:
    l = len(graph[k])
    out[l]+=1

print(out)
```

Outputs `[1, 2, 2, 0, 1]`

Comment: @Rachel if you're using Python 2 you can use `graph.iteritems()`, instead of `graph.items()` (`.items()` is from Python 3)

Comment: Thanks.. Sorry to bother you again. I am not suppose to use lambda as well. Is it possible to replace it with simple ones..??

Comment: @Rachel yep, you can use a simple function instead :) Updated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49853/discussion-between-rachel-and-traceur)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `Counter` :

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter(map(len, graph.values())) # map with degree as key and number of nodes as value
out = [a[i] for i in range(max(a)+1)] # transform the map to a list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the degrees of individual nodes by simply finding lengths of each element's list.

```
all_degrees = map(len, graph.values())
```

This, in your case produces the individual degrees, not necessarily in same order as the elements.

```
[1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```

Next thing is simply frequency count in the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
freq = defaultdict(int)
for i in all_degrees:
    freq[i] += 1
print freq
Out: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 4: 1})
```

As expected, `freq` now gives count of each values which you can then print, append to list etc. You can simply print values of the dictionary `freq` as

```
print freq.values()
```

Returns the desired list `[1, 2, 2, 0, 1]`. Or you can create an empty list and append values to it as

```
out = list()
for i in range(max(all_degrees)+1):
   out.append(freq[i])
```

Again returns `out = [1,2,2,0,1]` - the required output.